# Disable button focus border

Tags: jquery-mobile, focus, border

I have a Jquery Mobile page with buttons

When set the focus to a button with Tab, there is a blue border... (Only with IE when browsing in a WPF WebBrowser control)

[image]

I would like  to disable this border in the css, because when I click in the page, it automatically focus my first button...

It seems simple but I can't manage to do it...

For some reasons, I can't inspect the page to know the css property to disable.

What is the equivalent of "-moz-focus-inner" for Internet Explorer ?

Comment: Not sure if this works (input[type="button"]:focus { outline : none; })

Comment: I tired but it doesn't work...Any other idea ?